# in php friend system, how to print from friend table friends of my friends

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a friend system in php. A table called friends, has 3 columns. First for friends_id, second user_one and third user_two. Friends(friends_id, user_one, user_two). Where user_one and user_two are the ids of the users that are friends.

The following piece of code prints me friends of my friends.

```
<?php

$friend_query = mysql_query("  SELECT `user_one`, `user_two` FROM `friends` WHERE `user_one`='$session_user_id' OR `user_two`='$session_user_id' ");    

while($run_friend = mysql_fetch_array($friend_query)){

$user_one = $run_friend['user_one'];
$user_two = $run_friend['user_two'];

if($user_one == $session_user_id){
  $user = $user_two;
}else{
  $user = $user_one;
}
$friend_id = getuser($user, 'user_id');


$friend_query_two = mysql_query("  SELECT `user_one`, `user_two` FROM `friends` WHERE (`user_one`='$friend_id' and `user_two` != '$session_user_id') OR (`user_one`!='$session_user_id' and`user_two`='$friend_id' )   ");  


while($run_friend_two = mysql_fetch_array($friend_query_two)){

$user_one_two = $run_friend_two['user_one'];
$user_two_two = $run_friend_two['user_two'];

if($user_one_two == $friend_id){
 $user_two = $user_two_two;
}else{
 $user_two = $user_one_two;
}

$friend_id_two = getuser($user_two, 'user_id');

echo $friend_id_two;

 } //end while first
 } //end while second
?>
```

My code works fine, but how can I modify it in order to make it print only the friends of my friends that happens not to be my friends? (because some friends of my friends, happens to be my friends as well).

Comment: just exclude your user ID from the query using `<>`

Comment: any idea how to do this?

Comment: could not get any help from this

Comment: Actually there is a way I know, but not the best way, you can the existence of friendship between $friend_id_two and the logged-in user by setting a query from friend's table.

Answer (score 0):

I know just one solution for your problem, of course, it's not so fast,but feasible.
you can check The user's friendship in inner while >>

```
while($run_friend_two = mysql_fetch_array($friend_query_two)){
    $user_one_two = $run_friend_two['user_one'];
    $user_two_two = $run_friend_two['user_two'];

    if($user_one_two == $friend_id){
        $user_two = $user_two_two;
    }else{
        $user_two = $user_one_two;
    }
    $friend_id_two = getuser($user_two, 'user_id');
    ///// check for the existence
    $existence = mysql_query("SELECT 'friends_id' FROM 'friends' WHERE (`user_one`='$friend_id_two' and `user_two` = '$session_user_id') OR (`user_one`='$session_user_id' and`user_two`='$friend_id_two' )");
    if(mysql_num_rows($existence)>0) /// check whether the query get results or not
        echo $friend_id_two;
} //end while first
```

Comment: thanks for your help...unfortunatelly it did not work